# SQL Join on table with multiple identical values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have inherited a database where some tables contain multiple identical values.

table A
aId (PK), RowId, Value, CreateDate

table Row
RowId (PK)

Table A (20M entries) contains a lot of  multiple identical entries of RowId and Value (CreateDate would differ though), typical 20 identical entries for each RowId. I want to do this query:

```
select Row.RowId, DistinctA.Value  
from Row  
left join (select distinct RowId, Value from A) DistinctA  
on DistinctA.RowId=Row.RowId
```

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by rowid, value order by createdate desc) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the most recent row for each combination (use `order by createdate asc` for the oldest row).

Comment: Yes, looks good! Would this have better performance than the original query?

Comment: Your original query doesn't make sense (at least with respect to what you are trying to accomplish).